# Why does my Tkinter program only sometimes work? (invalid command name "4380768768update)

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

My Tkinter program only works on the first try.

It works on the first try but I get the error:

```
invalid command name "4380768768update"
    while executing
"4380768768update"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "4383331520check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"4383331520check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "4418904256_click_animation"
    while executing
"4418904256_click_animation"
    ("after" script)
```

On the second try, it doesn't work at all and I get the same error. It does not give me a reference line and the debug feature shows no breaks.

I think it has to do with how I use tkinter and custom tkinter and how I inherit it in the classes?

This is my code:

```
import random
import string
import csv
from os import urandom
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("green")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

ctk = customtkinter.CTk()  # creating custom tkinter window
ctk.geometry("600x440")
ctk.title("Login")


class Login:
    def __init__(self, ctk):
        super().__init__()
        self.login_win = ctk
        info_frame = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=ctk)
        info_frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

        # creating custom frame
        frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=info_frame, width=320, height=360, corner_radius=15)
        frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        text_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Log into your Account", font=('Century Gothic', 20))
        text_label.place(x=60, y=45)

        self.username = tk.StringVar()
        username_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, width=220, placeholder_text='Username',
                                                textvariable=self.username)
        username_entry.place(x=50, y=110)

        self.password = tk.StringVar()
        password_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, width=220, placeholder_text='Password', show="*",
                                                textvariable=self.password)
        password_entry.place(x=50, y=165)

        # Create custom button
        button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, width=220, text="Login", command=self.logged_in,
                                          corner_radius=6)
        button1.place(x=50, y=240)

    def logged_in(self):
        if self.username.get() == "Hi" and self.password.get() == "Bye":

            login_win.login_win.destroy()  # destroy current window and creating new one

            """
            Generate Password is a class that allows the user to generate a password and copy it, choose password strength,
            and store a profile.
            """

            class GeneratePassword(ttk.Frame):


            """
            View Profile is a class that allows the user to view previously generated and saved profiles through a listbox.
            """

            class ViewProfile(ttk.Frame):
...

            """
            Mainview is the class that holds Generate Password and View Profile and displays them when they're called.
            """

            class Main_view(ttk.Notebook):

                def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                    self.add(GeneratePassword(self),
                             text="Generate Password")  # creates tab for password generation
                    self.add(ViewProfile(self), text="View Profiles")  # creates tab to see previous passwords

            root = tk.Tk()
            root.title("PassX")
            main = Main_view(root)
            main.grid(row=0, column=0)
            root.mainloop()
        else:
            pass


login_win = Login(ctk)
login_win.login_win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to pare this down to a [mre]. This is way too much code to sift through for us to be able to diagnose anything. The error traceback(s) should tell you the line number(s) where the problem occurred, so you should start looking there.

Comment: Your could looks very messy, you cannot create multiple instances of CTk or CTk and Tk in the same program. There can only be one instance of CTk in the whole program and secondary windows have to be created using CTkToplevel. Have a look at the docs for this: https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/windows/toplevel

Comment: I just discovered that my program crashes only when my laptop is in light mode. In dark mode it works fine. Why is that?